# Trouble grouping form inputs as arrays before AJAX submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, object

I have a multi-step form I am working with that has multiple different areas (Company, Job Site, Contact, Product, etc.)

I would like to collect the form data as either an array or an object before I stringify it to be sent via AJAX. Here's a sample

```
<div class="row lmc-tab company-info">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Company Information</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[name]" placeholder="Company Name" aria-label="Company Name" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[address]" placeholder="Address" aria-label="Address" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[city]" placeholder="City" aria-label="City" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[state]" placeholder="State" aria-label="State" />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="company[zipcode]" placeholder="Zipcode" aria-label="Zipcode" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact[name]" placeholder="Contact Name" aria-label="Contact Name" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact[email]" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email" />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact[phone]" placeholder="Phone" aria-label="Phone" />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact[fax]" placeholder="Fax" aria-label="Fax "/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 job-info">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ship-to-site" value="yes" id="job-site-check"/>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="job-site-check">
            Ship to Job Site
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control disabled" name="job[name]" placeholder="Job Name" aria-label="Job Name" disabled/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control disabled" name="job[address]" placeholder="Job Address" aria-label="Job Address" disabled/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control disabled" name="job[city]" placeholder="Job City" aria-label="Job City" disabled/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control disabled" name="job[state]" placeholder="Job State" aria-label="Job State" disabled/>
        <input type="number" class="form-control disabled" name="job[zipcode]" placeholder="Job Zipcode" aria-label="Job Zipcode" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="test btn btn-primary" id="testBtn">test</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to get the inputs to be collected similar to a format below

```
company {
   name: value
   address: value
   ...
   }
```

So that I have an easier time working with the data in php.

First post. Sorry if I did it wrong but would greatly appreciate any help.

**SOLUTION EDIT**

Using the FormData object as mentioned below worked, using $.serialize() also worked once all inputs had been targeted.

Comment: You could give each input a extra class and combine on that, for example add class companyInput to the right inputfields and combine on those.

Comment: Don't overthink things. If you were to submit that you'd see the arrays in $_POST  as $_POST['company'] etc. You'd get the same result if you gathered the fields in a FormData object and sent that with AJAX. You just need to add the usual `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a cool object to group form data: [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Once you add a form tag with `id="myform"` You can create a new FormData like this:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var formData = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);

xhr.onload = function () {
  // Request finished. Do processing here.
};

xhr.send(formData);
```